# Is H2 database Replaceable

Tags: ignite

I have been working on ApacheIgnite in my organization.
 Somewhere i have read that apacheignite is tightly coupled with h2 database .
 Can I change h2 database to some other database in apache Ignite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignite does not use H2 to store or index data, it just uses H2's query parser, query planner and serialization, with a lot of customization over either one.

So you can't replace H2 dependency, but if what you really want is storing data in 3rd party database, then you can certainly do that via [3rd Party Persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store).

Comment: Thanks Alamar . That,s really helpful.